# Extending the Pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$ and $S^1$

Tags: fourier-analysis, representation-theory, fourier-series

Please correct me if I am wrong, but I understand the Pontryagin Dual for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and the circle in the complex plane as a set of representations for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ defined by the continuous homomorphisms
$$
\phi_k:\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\\
1\mapsto e^{\frac{2\pi i k}{n}}\\
k\in\{0,1,....,n-1\}
$$
Giving us $n$ different characters
for $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ in $S^1$.

My notes then move onto all of $\mathbb{Z}$, seeming to suggest that the map is defined similarly, as $1$ being mapped to a point, and the rest of $\mathbb{Z}$ following as $1$ is the generator.

Assuming the above is correct, how do we extend this to $\mathbb{R}$? I understand how to get there once we have representations for points in $\mathbb{Q}$, since it follows from continuity of the map, but how do we extend to $\mathbb{Q}$ in the first place? Something along the lines of 
$$
\phi_k(m/n)=e^{\frac{m}{j}*\frac{2\pi i}{k}}
$$
would seem obvious, but is there a good way to justify this?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question exactly? Is it something like "what is the Pontryagin dual of $\Bbb R$"? Notice that for any fixed real number $y$, the continuous morphism $x \mapsto e^{iyx}$ is an element of the dual of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @Watson Fundamentally yes, but I first want to know if my thinking is correct, and if not, how am I wrong? I feel that this will help me figure out if I am thinking about rep theory and the Pontryagin dual in the right way

Comment: @Watson doesn't $exp(ixy)$ not necessarily have zero imaginary part?

Comment: Even if the quotient map $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ can help to understand the dual of $\Bbb Z$, it is wrong to try to "extend" the characters to $\Bbb Q$ and then to $\Bbb R$, because you don't consider the same topology on these groups: $\Bbb Q$ is endowed with the discrete topology, while on $\Bbb R$ you have the "euclidean topology".

Comment: $exp(ixy) \in S^1 \subset \Bbb C$ has modulus $1$. I don't understand your question.

Comment: so to compute the character you would take the modulus of a 1 dimensional character rather than the trace? And then how is it best to think of the pontryagin dual of $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$, do you have any resources?

Comment: The Pontryagin dual of $\Bbb Q$ is quite difficult to understand, but the one of $\Bbb R$ is just $\Bbb R$ itself, via $y \mapsto \phi_y$ and $\phi_y$ the character defined by $\phi_y(x)=e^{iyx}$.